# Finding a particular keyword after a match from text file in python 3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, text, readfile

I have a text file which contains thousands of lines with similar pattern like
below.

```
year date hour:minute:seconds data4 data5 data6 data1:data2:data3:command data_1 value1 started
```

I want to read through the text file and find where the value1 has been changed to some other arbitrary value and get the year, date and time element from the line and calculate the difference in time

For example. The next matching line with keywords "command", "data_1", and "started" is in this line

```
year_2 date_2 hour_2:minute_2:seconds_2 data4 data5 data6 data1:data2:data3:command data_1 value2 started.
```

I want to find the difference in time in minutes or in hours. Any guidance how to go after the implementation would be really helpful. And then same way find for another data like.

```
   year date hour:minute:seconds data4 data5 data6 data1:data2:data3:command data_2 value2 started
```

Then check for the next similar match

```
   year date hour:minute:seconds data4 data5 data6 data1:data2:data3:command data_2 value4 started and so on...
```

Here the values value1, value2, value3 these values are not important only thing required here is to know whether it is changed from the previous value.

```
command_active = {}
previous_command = ""
seen = "false"

with open("common_files/total_logs" ,"r") as total_logs:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i in range(0, len(lines)):
        line = lines[i]
        if ":Command" and "started." in line:

            month = line.split()[0]
            day = line.split()[1]
            time = line.split()[2]

            current_command = re.findall(r"Command (.*?) started",data)
            current_command = str(commands_executed).strip("[""]")
            current_command = str(commands_executed).replace("',","\n")
            current_command = str(commands_executed).replace("'","")    
            only_command = current_command.split()[0]

            next_line = line[i + 1]

            for i in range(next_line, len(lines)):
                if ":Command" and "started."  and only_command in lines[next_line]:

                    month_1 = line.split()[0]
                    day_1 = line.split()[1]
                    time_1 = line.split()[2]
```

I could manage only up to this.

Required output:

```
   data_1 value1 : 25 minutes
   data_2 value2 : 10 minutes and so on.....
```

Comment: What is the format of date in your input file? MM/DD?

Comment: @RickTeachey Its just date as a number like 5 or 3 and so on...

Comment: A date is usually a month and a day combined. What does a date = 5 mean...?

Comment: Note: I have heavily edited my answer. If you read/tried to use it before, you probably should start again.

Answer (score 0):

This task is the kind of thing Python's generators were created for.

First we'll make a generator that grabs each line with contents you are interested in:

```
def get_interesting_line(file,*searches):
    with open(file,'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            if all(search in line for search in searches):
                yield line

# Use it like this:
interesting_lines = get_interesting_line(myfile,':command','started.')
next(interesting_lines)
# Or like this:
for line in get_interesting_line(myfile,':command','started.'):
    print(line)
```

Then we'll make another generator that returns a tuple made up of an item and the following item (or in other words, a previous item and current item) from any other generator/iterator:

```
def get_item_pair(iterable):
    previous = next(iterable)
    for current in iterable:
        yield previous, current
        previous = current

# Use it like this:
line_pairs = get_item_pair(get_interesting_line(myfile,':command','started.'))
next(line_pairs)
# Or like this:
for pair in get_item_pair(get_interesting_line(myfile,':command','started.')):
    print(pair)
```

Now we can put it all together and create another generator which will spit out a four-tuple composed of data, value, previous time and current time based on your criteria (we will use the `datetime` module to store the times as `datetime` objects).

```
from datetime import datetime
def get_command_file_delta_t_info(file):
    c_lines = get_interesting_line(file,':command','started.')
    line_pairs = get_item_pair(c_lines)
    for line1, line2 in line_pairs:
        value1 = line1.split('command: ')[1].split(' started.')[0]
        value2 = line2.split('command: ')[1].split(' started.')[0]
        if value1 != value2:
            #value changed
            year1 = line1.split(' ',1)[0]
            year2 = line2.split(' ',1)[0]
            #assuming date is MM/DD format:
            month1 = line1.split()[1].split('/')[0]
            month2 = line2.split()[1].split('/')[0]
            day1 = line1.split()[1].split('/')[1]
            day2 = line2.split()[1].split('/')[1]
            #now hours, minutes, seconds:
            hour1 = line1.split()[2].split(':')[0]
            hour2 = line2.split()[2].split(':')[0]
            minute1 = line1.split()[2].split(':')[1]
            minute2 = line2.split()[2].split(':')[1]
            second1 = line1.split()[2].split(':')[2]
            second2 = line2.split()[2].split(':')[2]
            #now create a couple of date time objects for initial and final times
            dt_i = datetime(year1, month1, day1, hour1, minute1, second1)
            dt_f = datetime(year2, month2, day2, hour2, minute2, second2)
            #strip out data
            data = line2.split(':command ')[1].split(" " value2)[0]
            #finally yield a tuple containing the data you want
            yield (data, value2, dt_i, dt_f)
```

As explained above, this generator is yielding items in the following format:

```
#create the generator
my_gen = get_command_file_delta_t_info(myfile)
#Get first generated item:
next(my_gen)
#produces:
(data1, value1, dt_i1, dt_f1)
#Now we can get the second item, 3rd, etc:
next(my_gen)
(data2, value2, dt_i2, dt_f2)
#get all the remaining items and do stuff with them:
for item in my_gen:
    do_stuff(item)
    # note that the first item in the for statement is actually the 3rd
    # item that has been generated. the first two were generated in the 
    # lines above. my_gen does not "start over".
```

As illustrated above, the generator is an iterable object that only proceeds to the next item in the generator when the generator is iterated over, e.g., using `next()`, or in a `for` statement.

Now we can do whatever we want with the file data, including make a function that will output it in the format we want:

```
def print_command_file_delta_t_info(command_file_delta_t_info):
    for info in command_file_delta_t_info:
        #get the time difference
        #time_diff is a datetime.timedelta object
        time_diff = info[3] - info [2]
        #now print the information you want:
        print("{data} {value} : {minutes} minutes".format(data = info[0], value = info[1], minutes = time_diff.total_seconds()/60))
```